# Sql Request SUM time

Tags: php, sql, sum

I have two tables, workers and schedule. The workers every day, they log their start time and end time work. The column total_time have the number of hours worked for every day.

```
CREATE TABLE workers (
    id,
    full_name,
    ....

)

CREATE TABLE schedule (
    id,
    worker_id,
    date,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    total_time

)
```

What I need I don't know if it's possible is, select the records from the schedule table and join the workers table to get the theirs names for a date range. Usually it's a period of two weeks and  them return the worker name with the number of hours worked for the requested dates something like  that.

1. John Doe | 2018-09-03, 2018-09-15 | 80 hrs
2. Worker 2 | 2018-09-03, 2018-09-15 | 75 hrs
3. Worker 3 | 2018-09-03, 2018-09-15 | 83.35 hrs

Thank You!!

Comment: Where is your try? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select w.full_name, '2018-09-28', '2018-10-05'
       sum(total_time)
from workers w
join schedule s on s.worker_id = w.id
where start_time >= '2018-09-28' and start_time < '2018-10-05'
group by w.full_name
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Use join and aggregation

```
 select workers.id, full_name,DATEDIFF(second, min(start_time), max(end_time)) / 3600.0
    from workers inner join shcedule
    on workers.id=shcedule.worker_id
    group by workers.id,full_name
```